# How to create a cell link sequence in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a linking sequence in a row in Excel, which refers to another row in the sheet. When I drag the cells to copy the sequence to the next coming cells, it doesn't follow the same sequence.

[image: Example]

For example, in the above picture, I created a link sequence in three cells, but when I copied the same to the 4th cell (j), it didn't pick the same sequence. Please help me with this.

Comment: How you have created this manually or Formula Precedents ??

Comment: So the value under J should be D? How did you link? Did you use any formulas? Please provide it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply first. I am using simple link i.e. if A is in D4 then '=D4' where i want D4  and yes i have used Formula Precedents

Comment: Yes the value under J should be D

Comment: @FarmanUllah - I updated my answer a week ago, did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. It's somewhat simplistic, but it should work as you wish.  You'll obviously have to change the cell reference for your specific sheet.

You should paste it in the cell `D4`.  Make sure you set `A4 = A1` and then past the code below in the cell two columns over, then copy and paste the formula every two columns.  It should work the same if you want to do every other cell as well.  I showed both examples below.  When you copy the entire cell, not just formula and paste it, should work as planned.

```
=OFFSET($A$4,-3,COUNTA($A$4:A4))
```

[image]

Comment: your logic is somewhat different, actually i placed A,B,C etc just to show there is some data (that can be anything)
Now if for example in data row, cell 1 has Alex, cell 2 has Andrew,  cell 3 had America then as per your suggested formula the data it wont return next datas as it is only focusing on First Character

Comment: @FarmanUllah - I updated the formula, this would should work. :)